# Inputting two separate integer numbers with no space between them?

Tags: java

I am making a lottery game and I am wondering if there is a way to type in two integer numbers, like 3 and 4 but type them in as 34 and have them read individually? I need to have them read individually as the game will reward if one of the numbers entered matches one of the randomly generated numbers. My code so far is this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Lottery {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
   Random random = new Random();

   int guess, guess2, counter;
   int win1000, win10, win1;

   int number = random.nextInt(10); int number2 = random.nextInt(10);
   System.out.println("Welcome to the Super Lottery! \nLet's Play!");
   System.out.println("Round 1 - you have 5 chances to win money");

   System.out.print("Enter your guess: ");
   guess = keyboard.nextInt(); 
   guess2 = keyboard.nextInt();
   System.out.println("The lottery number is " + number + number2);

   win1 = 1;
   win10 = 10;
   win1000 = 1000;

   counter = 1;
   while(counter < 5) {
      number = random.nextInt(10); number2 = random.nextInt(10);
      System.out.print("Enter your guess: ");
      guess = keyboard.nextInt(); guess2 = keyboard.nextInt();
      System.out.println("The lottery number is " + number + number2);
      counter++;

   if(guess == number2 && guess2 == number) {
      System.out.println("You guessed both numbers, but in a different order! You win $" + win10);  
   }
   else if(guess == number && guess2 == number2) {
      System.out.println("CONGRATULATIONS! You win the Super Lottery!" + win1000);
   }
   else if(guess == number || guess2 == number2) {
       System.out.println("You guessed one number! You win $" + win1);
   }
   }

   }
}
```

Comment: considering that the numbers can go beyond `9` then you'll need to find a way to differentiate things like `111` where the first is a single `1` and the following two are together as in _eleven_ etc.

Comment: You'd better use comma or any other delimiter (even space). Then you can parse each number individually. Look up [String.split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-), [Integer.parseInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) methods.

Comment: Btw what if the numbers were: `3 4` and my guess was `5 3`, you're not evaluating that case... (i.e. right number, wrong position)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since random.nextInt has 10 as an argument, that means the random generated number will be from 0-9.

With that being said I am going to assume the number that the player will enter will have be from 00 to 99.

You can use a String for that and  then split it into two pieces.

Check this code example:

```
 Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
 String number = keyboard.nextLine();
 int guess, guess2;
 guess = Integer.valueOf((number.substring(0, 1)));
 guess2 = Integer.valueOf((number.substring(1, 2)));
 System.out.println(guess);
 System.out.println(guess2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the substring method to separate the numbers by their index so for a visual example:

```
String numbers = "12345";

    System.out.println(numbers.substring(0,1));
    System.out.println(numbers.substring(1,2));
    System.out.println(numbers.substring(2,3));
    System.out.println(numbers.substring(3,4));
    System.out.println(numbers.substring(4,5));
    }
```

Which will print out: 
     1
     2
     3
     4
     5

If you want to separate with a comma you could do something like this:

```
    String numbers = "12345";

    char[] temp = numbers.toCharArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(temp[i] + ",");
    }
```

Output: 
    1,2,3,4,5,

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int number = in.nextInt();
int firstNumber = number / 10;   
int secondNumber = number % 10; 

System.out.println("Result: "+ firstNumber + " & " + secondNumber);
```